# Searching sales order grid redirects to dashboard in magento 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have used a custom module to add new columns to Sales_Order_Grid in Magento but If I search for Order_Id the page redirects to the Dashboard.

If I try to select sales/orders again I get an error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:104:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'increment_id' in where clause is ambiguous";i:1;s:6229:"#0
```

I have no idea how to solve this and could really do with some guidance please?

Here's the Grid.php code:

```
<?php
class Excellence_Salesgrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{


    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        if ($this->getCollection()) {
            if ($column->getId() == 'shipping_telephone') {
                $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
                $field = 't4.telephone';
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field , $cond);
                return $this;
            }else if ($column->getId() == 'shipping_city') {
                $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
                $field = 't4.city';
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field , $cond);
                return $this;
            }else if ($column->getId() == 'shipping_region') {
                $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
                $field = 't4.region';
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field , $cond);
                return $this;
            }else if ($column->getId() == 'shipping_postcode') {
                $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
                $field = 't4.postcode';
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field , $cond);
                return $this;
            }else if($column->getId() == 'product_count'){
                $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
                $field = ( $column->getFilterIndex() ) ? $column->getFilterIndex() : $column->getIndex();
                $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->having($this->getCollection()->getResource()->getReadConnection()->prepareSqlCondition($field, $cond));
                return $this;
            }else if($column->getId() == 'skus'){
                $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
                $field = 't6.sku';
                $this->getCollection()->joinSkus();
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field , $cond);
                return $this;
            }else{
                return parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumnAfter('shipping_description', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Method'),
                'index' => 'shipping_description',
        ),'shipping_name');
        $this->addColumnAfter('method', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Method'),
                'index' => 'method',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => Mage::helper('payment')->getPaymentMethodList()
        ),'shipping_description');

        $this->addColumnAfter('shipping_city', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping City'),
                'index' => 'shipping_city',
        ),'method');

        $this->addColumnAfter('shipping_telephone', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Telephone'),
                'index' => 'shipping_telephone',
        ),'method');

        $this->addColumnAfter('shipping_region', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Region'),
                'index' => 'shipping_region',
        ),'method');

        $this->addColumnAfter('shipping_postcode', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Postcode'),
                'index' => 'shipping_postcode',
        ),'method');

        /*$this->addColumnAfter('product_count', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product Count'),
                'index' => 'product_count',
                'type' => 'number'
        ),'increment_id');

        /*$this->addColumnAfter('skus', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product Purchased'),
                'index' => 'skus',
        ),'increment_id');*/

        return parent::_prepareColumns();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are adding some more columns to the admin sales grid?  It also sounds like you are working with a collection containing a join against a second table, you need to add the table alias name into the where statement with the increment_id column definition, so `table_alias.increment_id`.

To check this, and assuming calling `$this->getCollection()` from `Excellence_Salesgrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid` returns the collection, get the select object from the collection:

`$select = $this->getCollection()->getSelect();`

Hopefully you are using xdebug with an IDE and can set breakpoints in your code.  If so set a breakpoint and inspect the the `$select` object pulled by the line above.  Inside this object you will see a `_parts` array which describes the way your select statement is constructed.  Inside this you will see a `from` array which contains information about the tables which are part of the statement.  If you have a `JOIN`, this will contain more than one entry.

Under here you can also see `where` which will describe the where clauses which are part of the statement - this is where the problem likely lies.  You need to identify the alias for the correct table inside the `from` array and then where the `where` clause is added, instead of doing something like:

`$this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where('increment_id = ?', $id);`

instead do:

`$this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where('table_alias.increment_id = ?', $id);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and the solution works! I also needed to add some more columns to the Grid so instead of trying to reinvent the wheel I used this extension instead... http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/brandammo/extension/7956/ordersgridpro_custom_orders_grid

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked in my case:

$collection->addFilterToMap('increment_id', 'main_table.increment_id');